# Getting socket read interrupted in @Transactional method in spring when it is called in a thread

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Getting socket read interrupted in @Transactional method in spring   when it is called in a thread pool. Following below exception, we get    oracle deadlock exception as well for other threads.Kindly help to    resolve this.

```
   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:534) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        ... 15 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket read interrupted
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:993) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1205) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3666) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1426) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3756) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3736) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1063) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar!/:5.4.20.Final]
        ... 36 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: Socket read interrupted
        at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.handleInterrupt(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:258) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.read(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:180) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.readFromSocket(SSLSocketChannel.java:560) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.fillReadBuffer(SSLSocketChannel.java:328) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.fillAndUnwrap(SSLSocketChannel.java:258) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.read(SSLSocketChannel.java:109) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.doSocketRead(NSProtocolNIO.java:555) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readHeader(NIOPacket.java:258) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readPacketFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:190) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:132) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:105) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NIONSDataChannel.readDataFromSocketChannel(NIONSDataChannel.java:91) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForUnmarshall(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:764) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:429) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:407) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:268) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:655) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:270) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:91) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:970) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
        ... 45 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Transactions and other injected, container managed resources are not usually thread safe, so how you are calling them in your pool needs to be looked at. The error indicates the socket read is interrupted, so you'll also want to check settings and how long the transaction is up for before the error occurs. If you get deadlock exceptions on other threads, you must have locking issues with your application, causing everything to take too long waiting on the process that holds the locks.

Comment: Try adding jvm param to ur process: -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom for windows and -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom for linux